# How to find out which classes cannot be resolved by ProGuard Android

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-proguard

After adding ProGuard rules for all libraries I am using, I still get this warning:

```
Warning: there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
```

I know that I can probably use the `-dontwarn` option to get rid of this warning, but therefore I need to know which packages/classes/interfaces cannot be resolved. Android does not support a global "-dontwarn".

In the log file I find so many Notes and Warnings, but none of them seem to relate the above message.

Comment: actually it does: ´-dontwarn **´

Comment: well yes, that is true, thanks for pointing out. Although this is good for testing the build for other issues, it is not really what one should do. warnings are there for a reason. Do you also know the answer to my question?

Comment: Using ´-dontwarn **´ might be dangerous if later on you add a new dependency to your project without their respective ProGuard configuration. The dependency would be broken but `-dontwarn **` would mask the problem until it revealed itself (probably when your binaries are already in production).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you receive a `Warning: there were X unresolved references to classes or interfaces` then look for lines in your build log that contain the word `Warning`, such as this:

```
Warning: com.package.Class1: can't find referenced class org.library.Class2
```

Lines like this will tell which classes ProGuard is trying to work on and which classes can't be found in the input jars. In the example above, class `Class1` would reference `Class2` of a library but `Class2` was not found in the build path.

As you mentioned, you can simply add `-dontwarn <class regex>` to ignore those warnings but ideally you should check them one-by-one to make sure that your configuration is correct and all required dependencies are being imported correctly.